# How do I stop a image gallery from running onClick?

Tags: javascript, image, xhtml, gallery

I have a site that has an image gallery that changes images every few seconds using JavaScript; however, I want to know how to STOP the images from changing when a user clicks on one of the images.

So far, the images are rotating as planned, but I can't seem to get the "onClick" scripting to STOP the rotation when the user clicks on an image. I don't need to have an alert popup or need it to do anything, I just need it to STOP the image rotation when someone clicks on one of the pictures.

**Here's the HTML code I have:**

Answer (score 1):

```
else (getValue=='STOP')
{
    alert("STOPPED");

}
```

That won't do what you probably want it to do. It should be:

```
else if (getValue=='STOP')
{
    alert("STOPPED");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you missed out on the keyword "IF" in one of the lines of your code.

However, the way to create a terminable repetitive action is to setInterval and then use clearInterval to terminate the repetition.

```
semaphore = setInterval(somefunction, someinterval);
clearInterval(semaphore);
```

Example (I wrote this off-the-cuff, so there might be some errors, but you shd get the idea):

```
<img src="./images/image1.jpg" id="imageGallery" name="imageGallery"
 onclick="chooseImg(this)" />

<script>

var turn = setInterval(function(){imgTurn()},5000);
var images = function2CreateImgArray();
var imageN = 0;

function chooseImg(img){
  clearInterval(turn);
  function2DisplayImg(imageN); // or do whatever
}

function imgTurn(){
   if (imageN++ >= images.length) imageN = 0;
   function2DisplayImg(imageN++);
}

</script>
```

You could replace the setInterval with setTimeout.

```
var turn = setTimeout(function(){imgTurn()},5000);
```

But then you need to use clearTimeout to stop it:

```
clearTimeout(turn);
```

But if you use setTimeout, you would need to setTimeout for the next image display, so you would not even need to clearTimeout to stop the rotation.

```
<img src="./images/image1.jpg" id="imageGallery" name="imageGallery"
 onclick="chooseImg(this)" />

<script>

setTimeout(function(){imgTurn()},5000);
var images = function2CreateImgArray();
var imageN = 0;
var turn = 1;

function chooseImg(img){
  turn = 0;
  function2DisplayImg(imageN); // or do whatever
}

function imgTurn(){
   if (turn==0) return;
   if (imageN++ >= images.length) imageN = 0;
   function2DisplayImg(imageN++);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I think we should use setInterval for repetitive because we should push as much logic and testing to be performed by the javascript engine, since the javascript engine is more resource efficient than JIT compiled javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how would I integrate part of my original image source code into what you created? I simplified the image names to increasing by 1 integer, but in reality I wrote the code the way I did in my original question because I have to point to an external image source, and each image has their own unique names. Any suggestions? Thank you!